# ElasticSearch: Starting Multiple Cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

I started two clusters of ElasticSearch with different names but the other one won't show up either in `Marvel` or querying for health manually.

```
curl 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/_cat/health?v'

epoch      timestamp cluster          status node.total node.data shards pri relo init unassign pending_tasks max_task_wait_time active_shards_percent
1501062768 15:22:48  Cove_dev_cluster yellow          1         1      8   8    0    0        8             0                  -                 50.0%
```

But it's running on my screen.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are running both clusters (single nodes I believe in this case) on the same machine... In this case the nodes have a default port range setting of 9200-9300 and they are configured to bind to first available port in the specified range. More details available in [Network Settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html) documentation.

So in your case the other cluster is running on port 9201 most likely. If you check for Marvel or query the health manually on port 9201 you should find the other cluster.

However, if you want to have two nodes participating in the same cluster, then make sure that the cluster name matches in the configuration of both instances of elasticsearch you have running.

Hope this helps.